# Extjs 4 - checkboxmodel column position and header text

Tags: extjs4

Is there any way of changing the grid column position of the checkboxmodel from the first to the last column?

I'd also like to add text to the header instead of it being a plain checkall checkbox.

All help appreciated

Answer (score 4):

Changing the grid column position of the checkboxmodel from the first to the last column:

```
var selModel = Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel',{injectCheckbox:"last"});
```

Comment: Thanks for that - it worked a treat. Do you have any ideas on the header box text as well?

Comment: Did you try to use a column for it? but I don't know if it works exactly like the selModel

Comment: I did try, the trouble is the 'checkcolumn' doesn't have a checkall checkbox in the header. However, the more I look at the problem, the more it seems that it's the 'checkcolumn' that's needed.

Comment: If you want to use the selModel try to play with the css and add a label for header.